# Ошибка в Google App Script при отправке данных формы в Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Цель - отправить данные формы в Google Sheets для записи в соответствующие поля. Я использовал [эту статью](https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175), но мой скрипт выдает ошибку:

```
{
"result": "error",
  "Error in: ": {
  "message": "Invalid argument: id",
  "name": "Exception",
  "fileName": "Code",
  "lineNumber": 20,
  ""smack": "\that Code:20 (handleResponse)\n\tat Code:2 (doGet)\n"
  }
}
```

Помогите мне выяснить, какую ошибку я допустил в скрипте Служб Google, или подскажите, как можно самостоятельно ее диагностировать.

Google Apps Script:

```
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

//  Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
        var SHEET_NAME = "Table";

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

function handleResponse(e) {
  // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
  // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
  // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по стеку, в свойствах скрипта нет нужного идентификатора Таблицы. Т.е. `SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key")` ничего полезного не возвращает.

До того, как запускать вы должны установить значение ключа `key` в значение идентификатора Таблицы. Вставьте и запустите следующий код вручную

```
function customInit(){
  SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", "<Тут_ID_Таблицы>")
}
```

При внесении каких-либо изменений в коде, не забывайте выпускать и публиковать новую версию приложения.

Comment: Благодарю за совет, он помог мне найти причину, в скрипте не было ошибки, просто у меня не была запущена функция setup(), как так получилось не знаю, бывает ошибка перед глазами, а ты её не видишь ...